# How to Clear the hasfile Property on an asp:FileUpload Control?

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, file-upload

I have a .NET 2.0 fileupload control, and next to it a button, like this:

```
<asp:fileupload id="uploadedFile" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="upload" Text="Upload" OnClick="Page_Load"/>
```

Now, this is all on a page within a webpart (sharepoint, that is - for those of you unfamiliar with webparts - it is basically an iframe).  Notice also that I am calling Page_Load.

After the user browses for the file, the `hasfile` property of the `uploadedFile` control becomes `true` (it was `false` to begin with).  Fine.  The user clicks the button and the file uploads.  I have code in there that sends me an email to let me know a file has been uploaded as long as `hasfile` is `true`.

If the user pushes the refresh button in his browser, the page is reloaded, but the `hasfile` property is not cleared, and so I get sent another email!  (If I use Firefox's ability to reload without the cache, then everything is refreshed correctly)

*How can I clear the `hasfile` property on the FileUpload control?* Or how can I cause the page to skip the cache when the user reloads?

I don't mind calling a function other than Page_Load, but then it needs to be able to receive a parameter so I can also call it from Page_Load (on account of other things I am doing).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the functionality of clearing the `hasfile` property in the LoadPage() function which ,suprise suprise, is called when you refresh (as the page loads).

Or maybe instead of placing the functionality, code a function that implements said functionality and call it from page load.
[Guide Code](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t237593-cannot-delete-file-after-file-upload-asp-net-2-0-a.html):

```
private void clearFileUpload()
{
    fileUpload.Dispose();
}
```

OR

try to deal with the issue immediately after uploading the file.

```
private void clearFileUpload()
{
    fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Dispose();
    // fileUpload.HasFile is now  false
}
```

Comment: Likewise, this doesn't work for me when called from a button click event declared *outside* of the Page_Load() class in the code-behind .cs file. I haven't tested nesting the function inside Page_Load() and call it from outside.

Answer (score 0):

I do this to clear FileUpload:

```
fubanner.Attributes.Clear();
```